# Get previous value of an array and unshift it in the next array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on geographic web app with postgis and  postgresql

```
@slopes = Slope.order(:id)
@array_slopes = @slopes.chunk_while { |i, j| i.average_slope == j.average_slope }.to_a
```

I get an array of arrays of slopes (with geo coordinates) like :

```
[[slope_1, slope_2, slope3][slope_4, slope_5, slope_6, slope_7]][[slope_8, slope_9]....]
```

I m create a geojson linestring with @array_slopes, but get a broken line because I should have :

```
[[slope_1, slope_2, slope3][slope3, slope_4, slope_5, slope_6, slope_7]] [[slope_7 slope_8, slope_9]...]
```

I need to get the last slope from each array en push it in the next array for generate à continuous line with my geojson builder :

```
..slope3] => [slope3..
or
..slope_7]] => [[slope_7..
```

Something like this (but in my controller) :

```
<% @array_slopes.each_with_index do |array, index| %>
    <% array.each do |slope| %>
        <% @array_slopes[index +1 ].unshift(array.last) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You are missing commas between the inner arrays (e.g., `[slope_1, slope_2, slope3], [slope_4, slope_5, slope_6, slope_7]]`, not `[slope_1, slope_2, slope3][slope_4, slope_5, slope_6, slope_7]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward way of doing that.

```
arr =[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

```
arr.each_index.map do |i|
  if i.zero?
    arr[0]
  else
    [arr[i-1].last] + arr[i]
  end
end
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I have found another solution, see bellow ;)

Thks for your help

Comment: Ben, there are several. Here's another: `[arr.first] + arr.each_cons(2).map { |x,y| y.unshift(x.last) }`. See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Comment: Ouah..., I didn't know each_cons Thks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution :

```
@array_slopes.each_with_index do |group, i|
  next if group.empty? || i == @array.length - 1
  last_value = group.last
  @array[i+1].unshift(last_value)
end
```